# Why is Google ignoring my pages after a sitemap submit?

Tags: seo, google, search, xml-sitemap

I've submitted a Google sitemap with 12 links in, and Google has accepted the links (2 weeks ago) but it insists on only showing 4 out of the 12 pages in the search results.

Even when doing a site: in Google only shows these 4!

Any ideas how this can be corrected?

Comment: Google thinks the other 8 links are not worth including at this time. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you submitted a sitemap doesn't mean Google will index all of your pages(see near bottom of [this page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156184)). It merely tells them where your content is and in no way guarantees inclusion. If you want to help those pages along you should do your best to promote your website and attract quality links to your pages. They are an important part of SEO and will encourage Google to index those pages.

Comment: Should we start worrying about attracting links from the day 1 ? Should'nt we be working towards building the content ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your site in [Google's Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)? That will give you a report on errors, etc encountered while crawling your site, which should give some insight into what the problem is.

Other issues like nearly-identical pages, URLs, etc within your site can also affect search rank.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response.  This is a POC for a larger site and there are no problems reported in WMT.

Answer (score 0):

try to find out there if there something going wrong with .HTAACESS file.

Or else you can directly contact google webmaster for further assistance.